# What is the difference between Chrome App Shortcuts and Desktop Progressive Web App (PWA)?

Tags: google-chrome, desktop, progressive-web-apps, shortcut-file

When I create a Chrome App Shortcut using **... > More Tools > Create Shortcut...**
it creates a Shortcut that I can pin to Start, to Taskbar or to Desktop.

When I install a Desktop Progressive Web App (PWA) it does the same.

I know that PWA have some special features like Notifications, Offline Support, etc..

My question is: regarding Windows System, are they both just shortcuts?

Answer (score -2):

For creating [Chrome App Shortcuts](https://tomtalks.blog/2018/11/chrome-create-application-shortcut-option-removed-here-is-a-workaround/) after following the steps, this does indeed create a shortcut on the desktop. But it no longer uses the `favicon` and it opens in a regular chrome window alongside all other chrome windows. Shortcuts aren't the same as PWAs. A shortcut opens it in a Chrome window, in a new tab. A PWA opens in it's own window, as a separate app. They are more like Chrome Web Apps when they had those in the app store, except now you don't have to go to the app store to get them. Check this [blog](https://www.xda-developers.com/progressive-web-apps-chrome-how-to/) for more details.

Comment: re: "[...] it opens in a regular chrome window alongside all other chrome windows." 
  There is the possiblity to enable the checkbox **"Open as window"** while creating the shortcut. By doing so this will open the site as **stand-alone window** without the surroundings of Chrome (e.g. Omnibox, Bookmarks, etc..) which **feels almost the same as a PWA**.